# Custom Route Not Working in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, custom-routes

I have created one custom route

```
routes.MapRoute("Exams",
        "Exams/{id}/{name}",
        new { controller = "Exam", action = "SingleExam", id = "", name = (string) null },
        new[] { "MockTests.FrontEnd.Controllers" } 
    );
```

For this I am creating link as

```
http://localhost:61575/Exams/12/maharashtra+mba+common+entrance+test
```

But his gives error as

```
The resource cannot be found
```

SingleExam code

```
public ActionResult SingleExam(int id,string name)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Other Routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Register", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MockTests.FrontEnd.Controllers" }
        );
```

What wrong I am doing ?

Comment: Post your SingleExam action code

Comment: Can you show the rest of your route table?

Comment: Added other codes also

Comment: You should add this route in the top of routes before the default one.
And r u sure that the controller name is Exam not Exams ?

Comment: Answer it. Will mark as answer